# Angular toggle table row ng-class with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This seems not to be working for me. I've a `ng-repeat`,`ng-click` and `ng-class` on the `tr`. Clicking on the tr should toggle the class to `.error`.

Currently clicking a `tr` will change the class of all the table rows.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="studentApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        .is-grey-true { background-color: #ccc; }
        .error { background-color: red; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="StudentController">

    <table ng-hide="showTable">
        <tr ng-repeat="student in students" ng-class="{error : isGrey}" ng-click="toggleClass()">
            <td>{{student.id}}</td>
            <td>{{student.firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{student.lastname}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var studentApp = angular.module('studentApp',[]);

    studentApp.controller('StudentController', function($scope){
        var students = [
            { id:1, firstname: 'Mahesh', lastname: 'Sapkal'},
            { id:2, firstname: 'Hardik', lastname: 'Joshi'},
            { id:3, firstname: 'Sagar', lastname: 'Mhatre'}
        ];
        $scope.isGrey = false;

        $scope.toggleClass = function () {
            $scope.isGrey = true;
        };
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jhz4D/)

Comment: can you put a fiddle please?

Comment: @John: added jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hGE27/   heres a working fiddle

Comment: you shouldn't add the property isGrey to the students-object because it's something that the model shouldnt know

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every  refers to the same ng-class ($scope.error). You could define an array that contais the class for every row.

```
$scope.isGrey = [];
```

Refer to the specific class like this in HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students" ng-class="isGrey[$index]" ng-click="toggleClass()">
```

and change the toggleClass to the following

```
$scope.toggleClass = function (id) {
    $scope.isGrey[id] = $scope.isGrey[id]=='error'?'':'error';
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hGE27/

Answer (score 0):

You need to flip the value of isGrey:

```
$scope.toggleClass = function () {
    $scope.isGrey = !$scope.isGrey;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because each row is modeled to the same instance of `isGrey`.

What you need to do is associate each row with its own value of `isGrey`.

This means that you need to update the `students` object with a new property called `isGrey` as follows:

```
    $scope.students = [
        { id:1, firstname: 'Mahesh', lastname: 'Sapkal', isGrey: false},
        { id:2, firstname: 'Hardik', lastname: 'Joshi', isGrey: false},
        { id:3, firstname: 'Sagar', lastname: 'Mhatre', isGrey: false}
    ];
```

You can the update the `tr` tag as:

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students" ng-class="{error : student.isGrey}"
    ng-click="toggleClass(student)">
```

and for the code for the `toggleClass()` function to be:

```
$scope.toggleClass = function (student) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.students.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.students[i].id === student.id) {
            $scope.students[i].isGrey = true;

            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, that the one way of doing it, but I don't want an extra property on student object. :)

Answer (score 0):

As someone else has stated, the value of $scope.isGrey does need to be toggled or set based upon your necessary business rules.

That being said, based upon what you've described you want to color each row individually in which case you need to add isGrey to each element withing your array and toggle its value.

```
$scope.toggleClass = function(student){ student.isGrey = !student.isGrey; }
```

and in your markup

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students" ng-class="{error : student.isGrey}" ng-click="toggleClass(student)">
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm not sure if he want's such a property for his students object.

Comment: Yeah, that's right I don't want an extra property on student object. :)